# How to use Redis with AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elasticache

I want to use Redis with my nodejs app running in docker on AWS ECS. I'd either want a solution to run Redis in ECS or solution on how to connect ECS with AWS Elasticache

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/accessing-elasticache.html

Also that your app has to implement mechanism to read/write to Elasticache

Answer (score 5):

Run Redis in ECS:

Container definitions:

1. Image:redis:6.0.13
2. Port mapping:6379
3. Environment-Command:redis-server,--requirepass redis123456

Login to the Redis Server with password redis123456. It works normally.

[image: Image&Port mapping]

[image: Environment-Command]